# Is it possible to remove an inline style of display:none using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery tabs on my site. I've just installed a new jquery plugin (smooth zoom) for a map I'm using, but it wasn't dipalying . I checked firebug and it's creating an an inline style of display: none.

I've tried using the following to remove the display style, but it's not worked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs-4").css('display', '');
});
```

Is there any way I can completely remove all inline styles from this element using jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with `.removeAttr()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs-4").removeAttr('style');
});
```

and if it doesn't do on `doc ready` then you can try with `window load`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#tabs-4").removeAttr('style');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, but it only worked using the window load: command as above

Comment: Its because that inline style was generated via another script and that had been overridden on window load.

Answer (score 3):

Try to just remove the whole style attribute if you want all of the inline css on an element gone. I created a js fiddle, have a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/TfUhU/

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#demo").attr("style", "");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The code should change the display property instead of removing it.  You may need to change `block` to your desired property value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs-4").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This would clear all the inline style.

`$("#tabs-4").attr("style", "");`

Answer (score 0):

The link will be the trigger to show the div when clicked. So your Javascript will be:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
   $('.news').toggle();
});
```